# React-Native Static images don't show up in app on offline bundling

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I did the following

1. Commented

   jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
2. Uncommented

   jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

Then ran the following command from the root where index.ios.js is

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/ --verbose
```

Then from XCode I added main.jsbundle to the project ( Project > RightClick > Add files ...) but I am not sure where to put the assets folder that is created as a result of running the command, I tried adding assets folder to the project by the same method but static images still don't show up in the compiled binary. Where do I put the assets folder?

Comment: How are you require'ing the static images? React Native updated the way to do this in 0.15, which might cause issues for you.

Comment: you don't need to add the assets to xcode. Is your asset directory ios in the sub directory of ios? And as @AlexanderKuzmin said, which version of react-native are you using?

Comment: I am using version 0.1.7. I was able to solve the problem, look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running bundle command and generating bundles and assets there is a better way around.

Follow instructions in Manual Upgrades section here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html#from-0-13-to-0-14

Change Scheme to Release

Choose Option 2 in Appdelegate.m by uncommenting

That's it, now you can run your app on a physical device without the development server running.